# Changing x-, y-, and z-coordinate point in 3-D space image using mouse position - position array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, handler, mousemove

My application is asp.net MVC, I am trying to change the  x-, y-, and z-coordinate of an image.
I am using image handler:

```
  mpr.SetViewPlane(new Point3D(pX, pY, pZ), new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, -1));
```

in the view I am calculating the changes in Y position when I use the right mouse:

```
             $("#container1").bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                  lastX = parseInt(e.clientX);
                  lastY = parseInt(e.clientY);
                  pointZF = lastX - mX;
                   var htm1 = "ImageHandler.ashx?&pY=" + pointZF;
                   img.src = htm1;
              });
```

It works well, however the image jumps (for example position 1 to position 15); I would like to step from 1 to 15 position, any idea how I could that?